# Do-While loop in Java fails to stop

Tags: java, do-while

My file is compiling with no errors, however, when the user inputs "no" as their answer,the loop is repeated (rather than exiting the program and I have to exit the program due to infinite loops). Everything else works, my new contacts are being added to the file called "contactList.csv"

Should I consider using a different loop in order to have a parameter?

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

class ContactList {

List<Contact> people = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
Contact contact;


public void addContact() throws IOException{
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer;

    ArrayList<String> people = new ArrayList<>();
    do{ 
        Contact one=new Contact();
        people.add((Arrays.toString(one.getEverything())));                  


        String FileName="contactList.csv";

        for(int i=0;i<people.size();i++){
            System.out.println(people.get(i));
            // added a new file in the loop to worite to 
        try {
            PrintWriter outfile=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(FileName,true));
            outfile.println(people.get(i)+"\n");
            outfile.close();
        }   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            }

        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to create another contact?");
        answer=input.next();
    }while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

}
//rest of the code...



}
```

Comment: Your loop works fine for me. If I run your code (with the contact stuff removed, I'm just running the `answer=input.next()` bit) it work fine.  It goes while I type "yes" and stops when I type anything else.

Comment: Works for me as well. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Thanks, I'll clean up my code.

Comment: Also, please check, and possibly show, the code calling the posted method. You could get the same effect if the method is being called in a loop.

Comment: @Cindy Depending on the IDE you use, you can do this automatically. For Eclipse, go to Project - Clean - Clean all projects...

Comment: @Cindy For eclipse at least, (on PC) you can select all of your code by pressing `ctrl a` and auto-indent by pressing `ctrl i`. I'm sure other IDEs have a similar function.

Comment: I'm using the Command Prompt. I'm guessing my error is in my tester/driver file.